# opacity of p tag inside div on hover in the post

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make post in hover make transition in the top and bottom and I am using this code.

```css
.moade3 {
 margin: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
}
.fo2 {
 background: #000;
 height: 1px;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 transition: .3s all cubic-bezier(0.56, 0.28, 0.34, 1.0);
}
.block:hover > .fo2 {
 height: 40px;
 opacity: .3;
}
.block {
 background: #B8B8B8;
 height: 300px;
 width: 200px;
}
.t7t {
 background: #000000;
 height: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: .3s all cubic-bezier(0.56, 0.28, 0.34, 1.0);
 transform: rotatex(180deg);
 transform-origin: top;
}
.block:hover > .t7t {
 height: 100px;
 opacity: .3;
}
.shame {
 transform: rotatex(180deg);
 opacity: 1;
 font-weight: bold;
}
 .link{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
 .link:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<div class="moade3"> <a class="link" href="#">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="fo2 text-center"> Categories </div>
    <img class="image" src="https://i2.wallpaperscraft.com/image/summer_trees_autumn_mountains_nature_84572_200x300.jpg">
    <div class="t7t text-center">
      <p class="shame">Name of post and Discraption Area</p>
      <h5 class="shame"> Name of post  </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  </a> </div>
```

The problem here is I can not make the opacity of `<p>` tag to 1,
opacity of div affects the paragraph
tags need to put it in full opacity is (.shame or p & h5)
it must be inside the div too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5) to set the background color instead of opacity and then setting it back to 0 alpha value you can achieve this. This also retains the smooth animation.

```css
.moade3 {
 margin: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
}
.fo2 {
 background: #000;
 height: 1px;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 transition: .3s all cubic-bezier(0.56, 0.28, 0.34, 1.0);
}
.block:hover > .fo2 {
 height: 40px;
 opacity: .3;
}
.block {
 background: #B8B8B8;
 height: 300px;
 width: 200px;
}
.t7t {
 height: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: .3s all cubic-bezier(0.56, 0.28, 0.34, 1.0);
 transform: rotatex(180deg);
 transform-origin: top;
}
.block:hover > .t7t {
 height: 100px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.51);
}
.block:hover .shame{
   opacity:1;
 }
.shame {
 transform: rotatex(180deg);
 opacity: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
}
 .link{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
 .link:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<div class="moade3"> <a class="link" href="#">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="fo2 text-center"> Categories </div>
    <img class="image" src="https://i2.wallpaperscraft.com/image/summer_trees_autumn_mountains_nature_84572_200x300.jpg">
    <div class="t7t text-center">
      <p class="shame">Name of post and Discraption Area</p>
      <h5 class="shame"> Name of post  </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  </a> </div>
```

Comment: Could you mark my answer as correct ? I would love some reputation points :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately any children of an element that has opacity changed on it will also be effected.

Why not use RGBA on the background instead like so:

```css
.moade3 {
 margin: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
}
.fo2 {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);;
 height: 1px;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 transition: .3s all cubic-bezier(0.56, 0.28, 0.34, 1.0);
}
.block:hover > .fo2 {
 height: 40px;
 opacity: 1;
}
.block {
 background: #B8B8B8;
 height: 300px;
 width: 200px;
}
.t7t {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  
 height: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: .3s all cubic-bezier(0.56, 0.28, 0.34, 1.0);
 transform: rotatex(180deg);
 transform-origin: top;
}
.block:hover > .t7t {
 height: 100px;
 opacity: 1;
 
}
.shame {
 transform: rotatex(180deg);
 opacity: 1;
 font-weight: bold;
}
 .link{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
 .link:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<div class="moade3"> <a class="link" href="#">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="fo2 text-center"> Categories </div>
    <img class="image" src="https://i2.wallpaperscraft.com/image/summer_trees_autumn_mountains_nature_84572_200x300.jpg">
    <div class="t7t text-center">
      <p class="shame">Name of post and Discraption Area</p>
      <h5 class="shame"> Name of post  </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  </a> </div>
```

Comment: yea thanks for help  put  the p and h2 tags i cant hide them with opacity or display which property  i can replace those ?